# Problema con libreria GD en PHP

Tags: php, fuentes, imagen

Buenas chicos y chicas, quiero imprimir un certificado para un foro que se dictara en donde estudio e investigando encontre la libreria GD de PHP, vi algunos tutoriales y pues la verdad se veian "izi" Llevo todo el dia en esto x.x y no encuentro el error primero, no tenia siquiera imagen, pense que era la resolucion de la imagen, la cambie, jugue con ella, al final consegui mostrar la imagen, pero falta la funcion principal que es poner el texto sobre ella. A

Aca les dejo el codigo

```
<?php
      //Set the Content Type
      header("content-type: image/jpeg");


    $image = ImageCreateFromJPEG('certificado.jpg');
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $fuente = "ARIALMT.ttf";
    $text = "Carlos";
    imagettftext($image, 500, 0, 1739, 1499, $black, $fuente, $text);
    $filename = "certificadoout.jpg";
    imagejpeg($image);

    imagedestroy($image);
```

Hay algunas personas que imprimen la imagen con un tag img y quitan el header, pero la verdad es que me va igual, logro que se muestre la imagen pero el texto no sale sobre ella :/ por favor, ayuda D:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a verlo por partes, primero cargamos la imagen:

```
$image = ImageCreateFromJPEG('certificado.jpg');
```

Luego le decimos a la librería que escriba un texto sobre la imagen `$image` con un **tamaño de 500 puntos**, un ángulo de 0 grados, en las **coordenadas 1739, 1499**, que sea color negro, que use el archivo ttf **ARIALMT.ttf** que se encuentra en el directorio en donde se ejecuta el script y que diga "Carlos".

```
imagettftext($image, 500, 0, 1739, 1499, imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0), "ARIALMT.ttf", "Carlos");
```

Luego exportamos la imagen $image al navegador:

```
imagejpeg($image);
```

Al final liberamos memoria.

```
imagedestroy($image);
```

Luego deberíamos generar los headers  correctos para este archivo, pero vamos a dejar eso de lado. Necesitas enfocarte en los 3 puntos que he resaltado:

- Tamaño: ¿500 es demasiado grande? es posible que el texto se esté imprimiendo fuera de la imagen. Intenta con un tamaño 20 para iniciar, posteriormente lo puedes escalar.
- coordenadas: las coordenadas pueden estar fuera del margen, intenta con un numero menor; 0, 0 imprime el texto en la esquina superior izquierda.
- Archivo de fuente: No todas las instalaciones de PHP o de esta librería contienen archivos de fuente, debes asegurarte que el archivo que estás indicando existe en el sistema de archivos. Te recomiendo usar la ruta absoluta del mismo para evitar confusiones en cuanto a su ubicación, ej. `/var/www/fonts/ARIALMT.ttf`

Comment: Hola Solrac, gracias por responder :D  eh, lo que pasa es que la imagen es de 4000 de ancho x 3000 de alto. Esos fueron los valores que deje, aunque igual trate haciendo mas chica la imagen(directamente la imagen) y cambiando el tamaño de las fuentes pero nada funciono, la fuente estan en la raiz del proyecto, la verdad no se que pueda ser :/ revise las librerias con phpinfo() todo parece bien, revise mediante el terminal y me dice que ya esta instalada y en su ultima version.

Comment: Igual intenta poniendo la ruta absoluta, para el script puede que la raíz sea la raíz del sistema de archivos; `print_r(pathinfo('ARIALMT.ttf'));`.
Igual prueba otra fuente.

Comment: No lo he conseguido, intente hacerlo con el imagestring que le pasaria una fuente generica e igual nada :/ al final he conseguido hacer lo que queria con js.

Comment: Que lástima, pero lo importante es que pudiste resolverlo. Saludos!

Comment: Igual, Gracias amigo! saludos